# Mel to Python difficulty

Tags: python, mel

I have been following tutorials on Digital Tutors for scripting, and in some videos the tutor makes a tool that adds gamma correct nodes to any selected shader using MEL, for my learning I thought I'd try to rewrite the code in Python  but I am struggling to convert a piece of MEL code to Python.

The code I have so far is this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

selMat = cmds.ls(sl=True, mat=True)

if len(selMat) < 1:
    cmds.warning('Select at least one Maya or Mental Ray Shader to apply gamma correct node to.')

for mat in selMat:

    gammaCorrect_util = cmds.shadingNode('gammaCorrect', asUtility=True)
    rename_gamma = cmds.rename(gammaCorrect_util, ('gamma_' + mat))
    cmds.setAttr((rename_gamma + '.gammaX'), 0.45)
    cmds.setAttr((rename_gamma + '.gammaY'), 0.45)
    cmds.setAttr((rename_gamma + '.gammaZ'), 0.45)

    if cmds.attributeQuery('color', mat): # << error here

        connection_to_mat = cmds.listConnections(mat + '.color')
        if len(connection_to_mat) == 1:

            cmds.connectAttr ((connection_to_mat + '.outColor'), (rename_gamma + '.value'), f=True)
            cmds.connectAttr ((rename_gamma + '.outValue'), (mat + '.color'), f=True)
```

when I run this I get the following error:

> Error: Too many objects or values.Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 17, in  TypeError: Too many objects or values.

The MEL code where I think the issue is is:

```
if(`attributeExists "color" $mat`){
    string $connection_to_mat[] = `listConnections($mat + ".color")`;
    if(size($connection_to_mat) == 1){
        connectAttr -f ($connection_to_mat[0] + ".outColor") ($rename_gamma + ".value");
        connectAttr -f ($rename_gamma + ".outValue") ($mat + ".color");
```

I'm not sure how to convert and use the "attributeQuery" command in python in place of "attributeExists" in MEL, The tutor also defines the preseeding varables "$connection_to_mat[]" but this doesnt work in Python.

Comment: You have the original code, what's on line 17? It looks like a blank line to me, so either the code posted isn't exactly what you ran, or I miscounted - but I'm not really interested in counting 17 lines down again when you already know which one it is, and could have put it in your question in the first place.

Comment: Hi, sorry mate I'm new to this, It didn't post on the forum correctly, The code at line 17 in my script editor in maya is "if cmds.attributeQuery('color', mat):"

Comment: No problem, I've just edited it into the question for you

Comment: Cool. Thanks man. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: BTW, from [the docs](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/attributeQuery.html#flagexists) it looks like you need something like `exists=True` but the examples aren't very good. Hopefully someone who actually knows this API can answer you :)

Comment: OK so messing around with this and your right I needed an exist=True flag and a node flag to point to the mat variable from the for loop, having done this I now run the code and get this error at line 23 in my script editor:

line 23 code:  cmds.connectAttr ((connection_to_mat[0] + '.outColor'), (rename_gamma + '.value'), f=True)

Error: # Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 23, in <module>
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: Sorry this formatting looks really bad, Not sure how you make code obvious in this little comment window.

Comment: Ideally edit it into the question - if you can't do that (I forget the rep limit), you can always ask a dedicated question about the new error. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

`attributeQuery` only takes one unnamed argument, the attribute. You have to specify the node with the node flag, same as the MEL version.

```
cmds.attributeQuery('color', n=mat, exists=True)
```

listConnections returns an array. You'll need to check there are some connections and if so use the first connection: `connection_to_mat[0]`

Incidentally, if you specify that you want the plug, then you won't have to concatenate the string with ".outColor"

```
cmds.listConnections(mat + '.color', p=True)
// result ["someNode.outColor"]
```

This is better because there's a possibility the incoming attribute is named differently, or is a child of a compound. Example: `someNode.colors.outColor1`. Whatever it is, you can just feed it to `connectAttr`.